# Chicken Egg Class Interface in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I need some help understanding the syntax used in this problem for an assessment I took a while ago.

Add the missing code to *Chicken* and *Egg* so the following actions are complete:

- Chicken implements the Bird Class.
- A Chicken lays an egg that will hatch into a new Chicken.
- Eggs from other types of birds should hatch into a new bird of their parent type.
- Hatching an egg for the second time throws a std::logic_error.

This is the code template:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>

class Egg;

class Bird
{
public:
    virtual ~Bird(){};
    virtual Egg *lay() = 0;
};

class Egg
{
public:
    Egg(std::function<Bird *()> createBird)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Waiting to be implemented");
    }

    Bird *hatch()
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Waiting to be implemented");
    }
};

class Chicken : public Bird
{
public:
    Chicken()
    {
    }

    Egg *lay()
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Waiting to be implemented");
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    Bird *chicken = new Chicken();

    Egg *egg1 = chicken->lay();
    Bird *childChicken1 = egg1->hatch();
}
#endif
```

Here is what I've tried to complete some of the tasks.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Egg;

class Bird
{
public:
    virtual ~Bird(){};
    virtual Egg *lay() = 0;
};

class Egg
{
    int hatchCount = 0;

public:
    Egg(std::function<Bird *()> createBird)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Waiting to be implemented");
    }

    Bird *hatch()
    {
        if (hatchCount > 0)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("This egg already hatched!");
        }
        hatchCount++;
    }
};

class Chicken : public Bird
{
public:
    Chicken()
    {
    }

    Egg *lay()
    {
        return Egg(Chicken());
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    Bird *chicken = new Chicken();

    Egg *egg1 = chicken->lay();
    Bird *childChicken1 = egg1->hatch();
}
#endif
```

Obviously not much. I do understand the class extension of Chicken from the Bird class. I'm lost by some of the keywords/syntax used (virtual? function<Bird *()> createBird??).

For this:

```
Egg *egg1 = chicken->lay();
```

Are we trying to create a new egg object by accessing a variable somewhere?

I'd appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::function<Bird* ()>` is a wrapper for a lambda expression. You can implement a private variable `std::function<Bird* ()> hatch_egg;` like:

```cpp
class Egg
{
    int hatchCount = 0;

public:
    Egg(std::function<Bird *()> createBird) : hatch_egg(createBird)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Waiting to be implemented");
    }

    Bird *hatch()
    {
        if (hatchCount > 0)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("This egg already hatched!");
        }
        hatchCount++;
        return hatch_egg();
    }
private:
   std::function<Bird* ()> hatch_egg;
};
```

The way lambda captures can be done is with the syntax outlined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), but in short `[params_to_be_caprutred_from_current_context](arguments to the function) -> trailing_ret_type {function body}`. The wrapper is named as you would expect: `std::function<ret_type (parameter_types)>`, so `std::function<Bird* ()>`
is a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Bird*`.

Generally you would do something like:

```cpp
class Chicken{
public:
    Egg* lay(){
        // We don't need any parameters from this context hence [], but if
        // we want to add a parent to the Bird object and the constructor
        // would take a Bird* then it would be like:
        // return new Egg([this]() -> Bird*{ return new Chicken(this) });
        return new Egg([]() -> Bird*{ return new Chicken; });
    }
};
```